# How to duplicate columns in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there any efficient way, without using for loops, to duplicate the columns in a data frame? For example, if I have the following data frame:

```
  Var1 Var2
1    1    0
2    2    0
3    1    1
4    2    1
5    1    2
6    2    2
```

And I specify that column Var1 should be repeated twice, and column Var2 three times, then I would like to get the following:

```
  Var1 Var1 Var2 Var2 Var2
1    1    1    0    0    0
2    2    2    0    0    0
3    1    1    1    1    1
4    2    2    1    1    1
5    1    1    2    2    2
6    2    2    2    2    2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can replicate the column names (`rep`), use that as index to duplicate the columns.  By default, the `data.frame` columns can have only unique column names, so it will use `make.unique` to add `.1`, `.2` as suffix to the duplicate column names in 'df2'.  If we don't want that, we can remove the suffix part with `sub`.

```
df2 <- df1[rep(names(df1), c(2,3))]
names(df2) <- sub('\\..*', '', names(df2))
df2
#  Var1 Var1 Var2 Var2 Var2
#1    1    1    0    0    0
#2    2    2    0    0    0
#3    1    1    1    1    1
#4    2    2    1    1    1
#5    1    1    2    2    2
#6    2    2    2    2    2
```

Or as @Frank mentioned in the comments, we can also do

```
`[.noquote`(df1,c(1,1,2,2,2))
```

Comment: Surely you mean `\`[.noquote\`(df1,c(1,1,2,2,2))`

Comment: @Frank That is a unique way.  Could you post that as an answer

Comment: :) Nah, it's just a joke approach. The odds are very good that R Core will break it within the next few versions, I think. That's what happened to `\`[.listof\``, which since 3.2.0 (I think) has zero functionality (though it previously did what `\`[.noquote\`` does here).

Comment: @akrun Thank you very much again! This really simplified my code a lot.