# Can I use letters in alphabetical order to denote a duplicate column instead of numbers in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

[How to duplicate columns in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32504655/how-to-duplicate-columns-in-a-data-frame)

I am referring to this question above where the user who answered removed the suffix of a duplicate column using the sub() function that make.unique() automatically attaches. It appears the default method for denoting duplicate columns is .1, .2, and so on.

My question is can you use the sub() function (or does this have to be done in the rep() function as seen in this question?) to assign letters to duplicate columns instead? For example col1 | col1.A | col1.B ... col1.G | col2 | col2.A | col2.B ...col2.G and so on. This is what I would like to do instead for my dataset.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do this :

```
#Create a new vector to attach suffix
new_letter <- c('', LETTERS)
#Remove everything after "."
cols <- sub('\\..*', '', names(df2))
#Create a sequence column for each cols and get corresponding suffix
#and paste it to cols
names(df2) <- paste(cols, new_letter[as.numeric(ave(cols, cols, 
              FUN = seq_along))], sep = ".")
#Remove the ending "." from column name
names(df2) <- sub('\\.$', '', names(df2))
df2
#  Var1 Var1.A Var2 Var2.A Var2.B
#1    1      1    0      0      0
#2    2      2    0      0      0
#3    1      1    1      1      1
#4    2      2    1      1      1
#5    1      1    2      2      2
#6    2      2    2      2      2
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Var1 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), Var2 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
df2 <- df1[rep(names(df1), c(2,3))]
```