# duplicate and cbind multiple columns of data frame several but different times

Tags: for-loop, error-handling, apply, cbind, rep

assuming I have the following two data frames

```
set.seed(20)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n=700, min=1, max=10), nrow=10))
df2 <- data.frame("name" = colnames(df1), "n" = round(runif(n=10, min=1, max=20), 0))
head(df1[1:3])
head(df2)
```

and I want to duplicate and cbind every column of `df1` `df2$n-1` times. Basically, I want to do this

```
df1 <- cbind(df1, rep(df1[1],4-1))
df1 <- cbind(df1, rep(df1[2],1-1))
df1 <- cbind(df1, rep(df1[3],11-1))
...
```

for every column of df1 and probably would have finished by now doing it for all of the 70 variables separately :D but I want to find the elegant solution.

How can I do that efficiently? I guess a `for` loop or something with the `apply` family would work but I couldnt get it right. Also, the error in `for` loop or `apply` when `df2$n==1` like with `df1[2]` should just be skipped since this column should not be duplicated.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my thoughts were way too complicated and I tried stuff like this

```
for (col in 1:ncol(df1)) {
  for (n in 1:nrow(df2)) {
    if (df2[n,2]==1) {
     next
    }
    if (col > 70) {
     break
    }
    df1 <- cbind(df1, rep(df1[col],df2[n,2]-1))
  }
}
```

which did not work properly. The answer (adapted from here [How to duplicate columns in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32504655/how-to-duplicate-columns-in-a-data-frame)) is simply

```
df1 <- df1[rep(names(df1), c(df2$n))]
```